# Site template not working in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, breadcrumbs

Okay, so I'm developing a site in wordpress and I have two file templates "Default Template" and "Shop" in both templates I have;

```
<?php include('breadcrumbs.php'); ?>
```

and inside the 'breadcrumbs.php' file I the following;

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <?php
                    if (function_exists('show_full_breadcrumb')) {
                        show_full_breadcrumb();
                    }
                ?>
                </ol>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now these breadcrumbs display properly if it is in the 'default template' like this;

[image: Breadcrumbs]

But on the shop page display like this and I have no idea why as they're both including the same file;

[image: Breadcrumbs]

now I'm not sure if this would affect much of it but I am also using WooCommerce.
Hopefully someone can help! thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the CSS look like? Have you included it on the shop page? I'm assuming you are missing a stylesheet since your `OL` isn't styled at all...

Comment: Are you sure you're importing all the requires Bootstrap CSS? Might be possible that something on your shop page is overriding the default breadcrumb class

Comment: Yes, because on both pages I'm doing get_header(); and in the header.php that's where I'm calling the stylesheet pages so if I'm getting the header on both pages it surely it should call the same thing on both page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a css issue.  Something is overriding the styling on that shop page.  Use firebug to diagnose the breadcrumbs.  Or provide a link so I can look at it.  But Firebug will show you the ul styling right on the breadcrumbs and you can A/B between the default and the shop template.  Should be an easy fix with the CSS

Hope this helps.